# Ansible lookup filter works only if more than one item in hashmap

Tags: ansible, ansible-filter

I have this playbook:

```yaml
- name: "This works"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('dict', foo) | map(attribute='key') | list}}"
      vars:
        foo:
          bar:
            type: v1
          baz:
            type: v2

- name: "This does not work"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('dict', foo) | map(attribute='key') | list}}"
      vars:
        foo:
          bar:
            type: v1
```

When running this, I get the following output:

```
PLAY [This works] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
   
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "bar",
        "baz"
    ]
}
    
PLAY [This does not work] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
    
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"
```

You see, it prints out `bar` and `baz` as list in the first example, but instead of a list containing just `bar` in the second example, I get some `AnsibleUndefined` output.

What do I have to change to make these filters also work with a single-item dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `lookup` does not always return a list. And in your second case, if you debug, you'll see it returns one single object which is not inside a list:

```json
{
    "key": "bar",
    "value": {
        "type": "v1"
    }
}
```

2 solutions to get around the problem:

1. instruct `lookup` you want a list

```yaml
msg: {{ lookup('dict', foo, wantlist=true) | map(attribute='key') | list }}
```

2. use `query` in place of `lookup` which always returns a list and is better suited for this kind of processing (loops, mapping)

```yaml
msg: {{ query('dict', foo) | map(attribute='key') | list }}
```

Reference:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#ensuring-list-input-for-loop-using-query-rather-than-lookup